# please onkeyup ajax post twice to sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

onkeyup ajax post twice to sql
twice data to sql
insert data to sql twice redcord

```js
function myFunction() {
             var x = $("#number_2").val();
               if(x.length === 2){
                      $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "insert2.php",
                      data: {message: x},
                      success: function(data) {
                       $('#number_2').val('')
                      }
                      });                    
               }
             }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number_2" onkeyup="myFunction()" class="text-center fast form-control" >
```

Comment: welcome to SO ... please go through this [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This code works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#number_2").on("keyup", function (e) {
                // alert($("#number_2"));
            // let isSubmitProcess = false;
            
            //     isSubmitProcess = true;
            //     if (isSubmitProcess) {
            //      return;
            //     }
                e.preventDefault();
                var x = $("#number_2").val();
                if (x.length === 2) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "insert2.php",
                        data: { message: x },
                        success: function (data) {
                            // $('#number_2').val('');
                            // isSubmitProcess = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (x.length > 1) {
                    $('#number_2').val('');
                }
                
            });
        });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number_2" class="text-center fast form-control" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="number_2" class="text-center fast form-control" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let isSubmitProcess = false;
    $("#number_2").on("keyup", function (e) {
        isSubmitProcess = true;
        if (isSubmitProcess) {
         return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = $("#number_2").val();
        if (x.length === 2) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert2.php",
                data: { message: x },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#number_2').val('');
                    isSubmitProcess = false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Function not working {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 21
}

Comment: Fill out slow information, send 1, but if filling in quickly, send 2 times